# Get Markers WIthout Reloading - Google Maps V3

Tags: .net, google-maps-api-3, sql-server-2008-r2, reload, bounds

I've developed an application using google maps v3, .NET, and SQL Server. After submitting a search box a map will appear based on the address you typed in.

Now this is where the first problem occurs. I want to get the Map bounds to create the markers on the map. So what I do is reload the page after the map has loaded and I have the bounds then in the reload I get the markers from the database. Next problem is whenever the map gets zoomed or moved I reload the page again to get the markers. This leads to constant reloading of the page.

I know there is a way I can get the bounds and then get the markers from the database without reloading the whole page. This functionality is similar to any search done on google or yelp. Does anyone have links to examples or code examples of how to do this?

Comment: Show us what you have done

Comment: It's pretty ugly... I can try and simplify it, may take me some time though. Not sure if that would be neccessary, I did do some research on AJAX and that seems like it is what I need.